# Certbot installation failed in Amazon Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apache2, dependencies, letsencrypt

I have Amazon AWS running Ubuntu 18.04, I need to install Lets encrypt, so I tried following commands, when I install python3-certbot-apache it gives error of unmet dependencies. Can you please help me

I have run following command:

- `sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`
- `sudo add-apt-repository universe`
- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot`
- `sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-apache` -- **This command failed**

I have given here the commands and output

```
sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease

Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        

Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease        

Reading package lists... Done

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.24.32.12).

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
```

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot


 This is the PPA for packages prepared by Debian Let's Encrypt Team and backported for Ubuntu.

Note: Packages are only provided for currently supported Ubuntu releases.

More info: https://launchpad.net/~certbot/+archive/ubuntu/certbot

Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease

Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        

Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease        

Reading package lists... Done

sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-apache

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 python3-certbot-apache :

 - Depends: certbot (>= 0.26.0~) but it is not going to be installed
 - Depends: python3-acme (>= 0.25.0~) but it is not going to be installed
 - Depends: python3-augeas but it is not going to be installed
 - Depends: python3-certbot (>= 0.26.0~) but it is not going to be installed
 - Depends: python3-mock but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried the solution given in that answer , but still I get the same error.  I tried following commands: apt-get clean, apt-get autoclean, apt-get -f install : None of them gave any error. Then run apt-get -u dist-upgrade this also went through. Tried apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade, this show broken count as zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion given in

```
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/installing-certbot-on-ubuntu-18-04-problems/68778/5
```

I have changed /etc/apt/source.list first line as follows:

- Original Line: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
- Changed Line: deb archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe

After this change run apt-get update, then able to install the package and Certbot.